# How to manage negative rewards in policy gradient in keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, reinforcement-learning

The same basic question here, but 3 years old and no definitive answer:

https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/2405/negative-reward-penalty-in-policy-gradient-reinforcement-learning

The question is, if I'm doing policy gradient in keras, using a loss of the form:

`rewards*cross_entropy(action_pdf, selected_action_one_hot)`

How do I manage negative rewards?

I've had success with this form in cases where the reward is always positive, but it does not train with negative rewards. The failure mode is for it to drive itself to very confident predictions all the time, which results in very large negative losses due to induced deviation for exploration. I can get it to train by clipping rewards at zero, but this throws a lot of valuable information on the table (only carrots, no sticks).

Comment: Try to ask this question on Artificial Intelligence Stack Exchange (the same site of the linked post), provided this is more a theoretical issue.In any case, someone has already voted to close this post as off-topic.

Comment: Can someone explain in what sense this is off-topic?  I've asked all kinds of machine learning questions on  SO.  "Reinforcement learning" was an available tag.

Comment: Looking here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, I see software algorithms as an on-topic subject.

Comment: I am just saying that there are more appropriate sites to ask questions related to RL.